# Joomla showing only default layout not overrides

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides

I have created some Joomla articles and blog overrides. Both are working fine at local host (XAMP) but not on live site. Overrides for both can be selected from back end but displays only default layouts on front end on live.

Since the site was already live, previous overrides are working fine on live but not new. I can't figure out why.

Comment: have you selected the override file in the 'alternative layout' option?

Comment: @Ruchika yes it is selected. its working in localhost but when puch code to live it just display the default layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use only lowercase letters in overrided files names; i. e. myblog.php; not Myblog.php.

Best Regards
Oleg.